# what would happen if someone got their hands on my aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key?

Tags: aws

What would happen if somebody gets their hands on AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY? Does this somehow compromise my AWS account? or my buckets or whatever that might be?

I just want to know what an attacker can do with these keys.

Can someone explain to me in detail?

Comment: Not clear if the attacker's access to the AWS control panel was due to AWS Keys being compromised, but the effect would be similar if a malicious party used your keys as the jump off point: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/06/18/code_spaces_destroyed/

Answer (score 1):

> Do not provide your access keys to a third party, even to help find your canonical user ID. By doing this, you might give someone full access to your account.

From [amazon documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys).

Answer (score 1):

If you gave your access keys to someone, they can access everything in your account as per the policy attached with the key.

If you leaked your root account key of AWS. You need to disable the old key, generate a new key and change the key in all your systems.